# Modifying J-Query UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

i am using jquery-ui [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) , what i actually want is to add numbers with the accordion programatically, as the accordion list comes from the cms system , therefore when the client 
adds the list the number should be automatically added , following is the [page][2] using accordion for faq , I want to show numbers after the arrow starting from 1. Any suggestions , assistance will be appreciated.
Thanks

updated:

```
 $('#accordion').accordion({ header: 'h3', collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight: false});
```

updated 2 (Solution):

```
 $("#accordion h3 a").each(function (index, elt) {
    index++;
    var tmp = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<span class="num">' + index + '</span>' + tmp);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, that's not really the accordion that you want to modify but the enumeration of your menu.

This can be done by adding programmatically the index to the header like this :

```
$("#accordion h3 a").each(function(index, elt) {
    index++;
    $(this).prepend(index + " ");   
});
```

You can have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/VNJwS/ .

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm , just a quicky can i also add a separate css to the index , i mean just the numbers not the anchor

Comment: Also can you explain this function abit :)

Comment: In fact, the function `prepend` just add whatever piece of HTML code you want at the beginning of the element. Thus you can do something like this : `$(this).prepend("<div class='num'>" + index + "</div>");`.